# PHP loads extensions when called through CLI, but not through Apache

Tags: windows, php, apache-2.4, extension

PHP for me only loads exensions perfectly when called from the CLI, but not when I load pages through Apache.

For example, this is the output of `php -m`:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib
```

However, when run through Apache:
 1. In `phpinfo()`, OpenSSL support shows up as "disabled".
 2. `extension_loaded("curl")` is `false`
 3. `get_loaded_extensions()` doesn't include `curl` or `OpenSSL`.
 4. Trying to use any of the extensions's functions fails.

Here's `var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());` when running through Apache:

```
array(28) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Core"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "bcmath"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "calendar"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "ctype"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "date"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "filter"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "hash"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "iconv"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "json"
  [9]=>
  string(3) "SPL"
  [10]=>
  string(4) "pcre"
  [11]=>
  string(8) "readline"
  [12]=>
  string(10) "Reflection"
  [13]=>
  string(7) "session"
  [14]=>
  string(8) "standard"
  [15]=>
  string(7) "mysqlnd"
  [16]=>
  string(9) "tokenizer"
  [17]=>
  string(3) "zip"
  [18]=>
  string(4) "zlib"
  [19]=>
  string(6) "libxml"
  [20]=>
  string(3) "dom"
  [21]=>
  string(3) "PDO"
  [22]=>
  string(4) "Phar"
  [23]=>
  string(9) "SimpleXML"
  [24]=>
  string(3) "xml"
  [25]=>
  string(9) "xmlreader"
  [26]=>
  string(9) "xmlwriter"
  [27]=>
  string(14) "apache2handler"
}
```

---

OS: `Windows 10 1809, up to date.`

`php -v`:

```
PHP 7.4.5 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2020 16:17:34) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

`httpd`:  Apache 2.4.43 Win64 from https://www.apachelounge.com/

PHP and Apache interacting through this in `httpd.conf` (mod_php):

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/<path_to_PHP>/PHP7/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

There is only one Apache+PHP install on this machine.

---

What I've tried:

1. Confirmed that PHP is using the same ini file in both modes. If I disable extensions from the ini file, they stop showing in `php -m` (as they should).
2. (Re)installing MS Visual Studio C++ Redistributable 2015-19 (both x86 and x64).
3. Restarting `httpd`.
4. Restarting PC.
5. Reinstalling PHP and Apache.
6. `display_startup_errors=on` and then checking logs. There is no relevant info in both Apache and PHP error logs.
7. Confirmed PHP is running in ZTS in `php.exe -v`, "Thread Safety" shows up as enabled in `phpinfo()` through Apache.

Please help. I need this webserver up and running, and this is driving me crazy.

Comment: "using the same ini file", but there may be more than one. Check phpinfo for "Additional .ini files parsed" and compare them.

Comment: Would you mind adding the loadfile and loadmodule directives concerning openssl and curl to your question?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I'm not sure what you're talking about? PHP extensions are loaded by adding (or uncommenting) them in `php.ini`.

Comment: Got it from https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=1641. Also, you could avoid your problem with fcgi https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=39070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by replacing the Apache Lounge binaries with ones from [Apache Haus](https://www.apachehaus.com/).

I just replaced the old `Apache24` folder with the new one, but retained the old `conf` folder. No other changes needed to be made.